# Csv data reading issue

Tags: java, csv, parsing, apache-spark

Sample csv data:

```
1,"Robert,Adams,Washington,US
2,"Madhu",Grant,Oregon,US
3,Mohan,Young,Texas,US
```

First entry consists of two columns 1 RobertAdamsWashingtonUS

Rest two are printed right, in first entry application searches for closing double quotes and all the rest of the columns are considered as one column

And shows the error Invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter. What should be the approach to read this csv properly? (JAVA)

Comment: Well ... "shit in => shit out". Correct the CSV file!

Comment: yeah thats the last option right. because data is very large and i will have to check each and every line

Comment: So, what are actually asking? How to programmatically correct a CSV file? This is a very complicated thing (and thus too broad for SO). There are so many things that could go wrong in such a text file.

Comment: yeah i understand that its too broad. But if their is solution then yes, programmatically How to do? I tried but no luck

Answer (score 1):

> What should be the approach to read this csv properly.

The correct approach is to reject it.  It is malformed.

- If we don't allow line separators in quotes, then line 1 has a field that starts with a double quote but has no closing double quote.
- If we do allow line separators within quotes, then the first line continues onto the second one, but then the characters after `2,"` are illegal.

(It is up to you to decide whether line separators within quotes make sense for your application.)

I would not recommend that you try to treat this data as "good".  It is clearly incorrect, and accepting incorrect data as correct is dangerous.

If you are going to attempt to continue parsing, you should skip either line 1, or both lines 1 and 2.

You added this:

> [The CSV file] is very large and I will have to check each and every line

The program should do the checking, not you.  Programs are lot more reliable at doing mundane repetitive tasks ... if coded correctly.

You can make (manual) correction of errors in your CSV simpler by including a line number in the error messages.  But a better approach would be to create the CSV file in a way that doesn't allow errors to creep in.

> How to do it programatically?

Use an existing Java CSV reader library.  There are lots to choose from.

Comment: No.  Skip the bad lines and keep parsing.  But when you get to the end, reject the entire file and print a list of all of the errors / line numbers so that they can be corrected in a batch.

Comment: In fact, a better solution would be to validate the CSV before you run the Java program.

Comment: Data shown by the OP looks malformed indeed, unless.. the fields are not quoted (i.e. the quotes are part of the field data) which is also a valid csv option. Of course, no field can contain a comma then. But most likely in this case the csv is just malformed.